# Read from stdin until EOF

Tags: c, stdin, unistd.h

I am having trouble reading from stdin constantly until CTRL+D is pressed. I have to use `read()` from unistd.h. I am trying to simulate the cat function. Is there a way to make my buffer (which I print with %s) to look neat without the unnecessary spaces from `read(STDIN_FILENO, buf, 256)`?

Comment: Without seeing the code it's difficult to know what to suggest.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what your problem is, since you've posted no code, no error messages, and no output (expected or actual), but here's a shot in the dark:  The read function doesn't null terminate for you, so you should be doing: `int rd = read(STDIN_FILENO, buf, 255); buf[rd]=0x0;`, assuming buf is declared as `char buf[256]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am trying to simulate the cat function.

Here is a start:

```
ssize_t nread, nwrite;

while ((nread = read(STDIN_FILENO, buf, sizeof buf)) > 0) {
    nwrite = write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf, nread);
    /* Error handling and partial writes left as exercise. */
}
```

Comment: Thanks i already have this piece of code, the problem is the sizeof(buf).. And found a little mistake in my code i am using prinf for the buf after reading......

Comment: @Alex What's the problem with the `sizeof` ?

Comment: Well sorry it is late and i didnt notice that i had a printf() before my code for read/write stdin/out and was causing some chaos ;D.. Anyways will post some code after i am done..